# Spring fails to forward the request to the target controller and its method

Tags: java, spring-mvc

We have an application where Spring handles any urls with base_path/mvc/*

In that we have one controller A as below which tries to forward the request to another controller where the forward path would be "base_path/mvc/controllerB/handleY"

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controllerA")
public class A {
  
  @RequestMapping("/handleX")
  public String handleX(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  
     String forwardUrl = service.performAction(request,response);

     return "forward:/" + forwardUrl;

  }

}
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controllerB")
public class B {
  
  @RequestMapping("/handleY", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody
  public String handleY(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     
    // Performs some action and writes the json to response

     return null;

  }

}
```

However when the "return "forward:/" + forwardUrl;" statement is executed, spring is not forwarding the request to the ControllerB. I have setup break points however it does not break there but ends in ControllerA itself.

We are not explicitly using redirect:/ as we do not want to lose the request parameters that are sent to ControllerA when the request comes it.

It would be a great help on why this issue is happening. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can autowire controller B in controller A, controllers are just like other spring beans, and call `handleY` method

Comment: We can do that but it defeats the purpose of Dependency Injection of Spring

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, I think you need to redirect to ControllerB and for attributes that you want to pass you can send them using HttpSession or Cookies

Comment: This would be last resort if there is no other solution